# Is this function of a Brownian motion a martingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales

$B_t$ is a Brownian motion and $Y_t:=e^{aB_t+bt}$ for $t\ge0$. For which $a, b\in\Bbb R$ is $Y_t$ a martingale?

My calculations with the martingale property lead me to the presumption that it is not a martingale except for $a=b=0$. But how can I prove that properly? (My main problem is that I am obtaining expected values that I can't calculate.)

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions

Comment: A martingale needs to have constant expectation. Verify for which constants $a,b$ this is the case using the fact that $B_t \sim N(0,t)$ (see the previous comment). It is not true that $a=b=0$ is necessary for $Y$ to be a martingale, so there is something wrong about your calculations.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your valuable hints. They lead to $b=-a^2/2$. Your idea with the constant expectation leads much quicker to that equation than the martingale property. But isn't there a problem with that approach? $Y_t$ could have constant expectation but still be no martingale. So I have to go the complicated way over the martingale property anyway and the idea with the constant expectation is simpler but not sufficient for a martingale?

Comment: Constant expectation is just a consequence of the martingale property. I don't think it is a sufficient to show that it is a martingale.

Comment: Looking at conditional expectation is enough. Such an approach is enough in this case but in general you'd use Ito Formula.